# Proper Syntax for 3 table SELECT query

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I've got 3 tables:

- tblPosts
- tblComments
- tblUsers

I'm trying to get a listing of Posts along with associated Comments. The tricky part seems to be getting the Posts and Comments to show the proper author (User). This is the closest I get but then the Posts authors are incorrect. I'm grouping my CFOutput on "pid", so I only get each post one time as I would expect.

```
SELECT tblPosts.pid
       , tblPosts.title
       , tblPosts.description
       , tblPosts.price
       , tblPosts.datecreated AS pdate
       , tblPosts.image1
       , tblComments.comment
       , tblComments.datecreated AS cdate
       , tblUsers.fname
       , tblUsers.lname
FROM   tblPosts
          LEFT JOIN tblComments ON tblPosts.pid = tblComments.pid
          LEFT JOIN tblUsers ON tblComments.uid = tblUsers.uid
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: If you plan to group your output on pid, you need an order by clause in your query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since both tables contain an author id, you must to JOIN to tblUser twice: once for posts and once for comments. That means you must use a table alias to differentiate between the two. Something along these lines, where `pa` is the alias for "Post Author" and `ca` the alias for "Comment Author".

```
SELECT p.pid
       , p.title  
       , ... 
       , pa.fname AS PostAuthorFirstName
       , pa.lname AS PostAuthorLastName
       , ca.fname AS CommentAuthorFirstName
       , ca.lname AS CommentAuthorLastName
FROM tblPosts p 
        LEFT JOIN tblUsers pa ON pa.uid = p.uid
        LEFT JOIN tblComments c ON p.pid = c.pid
        LEFT JOIN tblUsers ca ON ca.uid = c.uid
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and your explanation helped me understand WHY it worked so I can reproduce this in other scenarios. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Leigh, if I have another question about this same query and adding another table to it, should I edit/ask here or start a new question? Thx!

Comment: @MikeyJ - It is better to open a new question.

Comment: [Here you go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413615/proper-join-for-adding-a-4th-table-to-a-query), thx!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with all the fields in you tables. Join the post to the users table as well to get the specific users for writing posts.

How about trying this:

```
SELECT p.pid
       ,p.title
       ,p.description
       ,p.price
       ,p.datecreated AS pdate
       ,p.image1
       ,c.comment
       ,c.datecreated AS cdate
       ,u1.fname AS CommentAuthorsName
       ,u1.lname AS CommentAuthorsLastName
       ,u2.fname AS PostAuthorName
       ,u2.lname AS PostAuthorLastName
FROM tblPosts p
LEFT JOIN tblComments c
ON p.pid = c.pid
LEFT JOIN tblUsers u1
ON c.uid = u1.uid
LEFT JOIN tblUsers u2
ON p.uid = u2.uid
```