# Proper JOIN for Adding a 4th Table to a Query

Tags: sql, join, coldfusion

Asked a similar question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326679/proper-syntax-for-3-table-select-query/) but this extends it.

Here's the original query:

```
SELECT  p.pid
    , p.title
    , p.description
    , p.price
    , p.datecreated AS pdate
    , p.image1
    , c.cid
    , c.comment
    , c.datecreated AS cdate
    , pa.fname AS PFName
    , pa.lname AS PLName
    , ca.fname AS CFName
    , ca.lname AS CLName
FROM tblPosts p
LEFT JOIN tblUsers pa ON pa.uid = p.uid
LEFT JOIN tblComments c ON p.pid = c.pid
LEFT JOIN tblUsers ca ON ca.uid = c.uid
ORDER BY p.pid
```

I need to add a fourth table (tblPostStatus) that holds the status of each post(statusType) which can be one of 2 different values. When I try to add the JOIN I seem to get duped rows, one for each row in tblPostStatus (there are 3 records in this table). This table has fields sid, pid, uid, statusType.

New Query:

```
    SELECT  p.pid
    , p.title
    , p.description
    , p.price
    , p.datecreated AS pdate
    , p.image1
    , c.cid
    , c.comment
    , c.datecreated AS cdate
    , pa.fname AS PFName
    , pa.lname AS PLName
    , ca.fname AS CFName
    , ca.lname AS CLName
    , ps.statusType
FROM tblPosts p
LEFT JOIN tblUsers pa ON pa.uid = p.uid
LEFT JOIN tblComments c ON p.pid = c.pid
LEFT JOIN tblUsers ca ON ca.uid = c.uid
LEFT JOIN tblPostStatus ps ON p.pid = ps.pid
ORDER BY p.pid
```

See query result pics:
[image: Original]

[image: New]

Do these results look proper or am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize the images wouldn't be linked. Right click them and choose to Open in new Tab and you should be ok.

Comment: The results look proper but of course repeated rows can cause display problems/complexity, what exactly is the idea behind tblPostStatus? Why is there multiple rows for each post in it?

Comment: Each Post can have multiple status records. A user can basically "Claim" the post and then other users can be "Next" in line. There can be only one "Claim" status at a time but multiple "Next" statuses. I initially thought to store this info in the Posts table but then thought that might not be the best idea regarding Normalization practices.

Comment: I assume there is always *at least one* status record for each post, correct? If there are multiple statuses, which one do you want to display - and why?

Comment: There can be posts that no one has claimed, so basically, 0,1 or 2 is what I've been trying to use. 0=not claimed, 1=claimed, 2=next. Technically, I haven't had a need to display the status but I DO need to change some elements on the page based on the status such as enable/disable buttons and change background highlighting on certain comments. Hmm...writing it out like this has got me thinking about how this should all be done. Would it help you if I explained in a little more detail, how the design should function?

Comment: (Edit) Well not unless it is more involved than "do X when the current status == 0, do Y when status == 1, ..". But in terms of the query, we still need to know which status to return when there are multiples.

Comment: So my issue might be more of a design thing. The basic idea is very similar to the design of this site where my "post" would be the "question" and then there are comments underneath. The comments section is where people "claim" or "next" the post. I've been trying to hilite individual comments based on if they are a "claim" or a "next" but they are always showing as "claim" status even if there are one or more "next" statuses. "Claim" takes precedence over "next". I struggle whether to use the Comments table to manage the status of the post since status seems to be more related to a post.

Comment: (Edit) Sorry for the delay. I do not think you should involve the comments table, because it sounds like status is only related to "post" and "author". Assuming there is can only be one status per post + user, you could join status back to the user and post tables (on comment author). That would give you a single status per comment record. [Here is an example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e444f/1/0). If you want to associate it with the post, you would need to join it again, but this time on the post author id.

Comment: Thanks Leigh, this is working perfectly! I fooled around with the "AND" in that last join but couldn't get the results I was looking for. Technically, a user can comment on a post multiple times and only a "claim" or "next" comment should receive a status, so in my case, all comments for a user were being hilighted even if only one of them was the "claim" or "next" comment. I was able to work around this since there is always a predefined piece of text in the comment in the cases where there should be a status so I can do conditional formatting based on that in combination with the status.

Comment: Re: *a user can comment on a post multiple times and only a "claim" or "next" comment should receive a status* I was with you until that part ;-) (Ignoring *how* you are presenting this visually for a moment..) Just to be sure, a "status" is only associated with a post and user, not the individual comments, correct?

Comment: Ha! Yes, I worded that oddly. Let's say someone posts a comment saying "Hello World" then afterwards, they click a button on the Post that sets the statusType field in tblPostStatus to "1" and it ALSO creates a comment with the text "Claimed". So we definitely need to track which user "claimed" the post but I also need to conditionally format the particular comments that are the "Claimed" ones. Make sense? Should it maybe be done a different way?

Comment: (Tried to move this to chat, but you do not have enough rep yet) Hm.. that is a little different than what we discussed earlier. If it is the "*comment*" (not just a "user") that is linked to status then there *is* a relationship between the two tables. That brings us back to your earlier thought about storing status in the comments table. How else is status used in your application? ie What would the impact be if status were associated w/"comment" versus post+user? (Just trying to clarify the db relationships)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36173/discussion-between-leigh-and-mikeyj)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Summary from chat)

The overall requirements changed a bit. Ultimately "Status" is related to a post, user *and* comment record, so status was moved to the comment table. An additional requirement was added: identify posts with "claim" comments.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b3a4/2/0)

```
SELECT  p.pid
    , p.title
    , c.cid
    , c.comment
    , c.statusType 
    , COALESCE(cnt.HasClaim, 0) AS HasClaim
    , pa.fname AS PFName
    , pa.lname AS PLName
    , ca.fname AS CFName
    , ca.lname AS CLName
FROM tblPosts p
      LEFT JOIN tblUsers pa ON pa.uid = p.uid
      LEFT JOIN tblComments c ON p.pid = c.pid
      LEFT JOIN tblUsers ca ON ca.uid = c.uid
      LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT pid, COUNT(*) AS HasClaim
          FROM  tblComments 
          WHERE statusType = 1
          GROUP BY pid
        ) cnt ON cnt.pid = p.pid
ORDER BY p.pid, c.cid
```